# How to show warning when using functions incorrectly according to JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, jsdoc

I'm using JSDoc to document my Javascript functions and add type annotations.

In Visual Studio, I am getting intellisense for these functions, which is great. However, if I use an incorrect type (e.g. an integer for a parameter annotated as a string), I don't see any kind of warning about it anywhere. I have the same problem if I use the wrong number of arguments for a function.

I've looked through all the settings in Tools > Options, but didn't see anything relevant. I also use ReSharper, but didn't see anything in R# options either.

Is there some way to get Visual Studio to show a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [link](https://www.techcartnow.com/typescript-checking-javascript-file-visual-studio-2017-checkjs-ts-check-ts-nocheck-ts-ignore/) with some answers. There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Enable it for all Javascript files by adding a `tsconfig.json` to your project's root directory, with `checkJs: true"
2. Enable it for specific Javascript files by adding `// @ts-check` at the start of the file

In my case however, I wanted to enable this in Razor files, which have all have a `script` tag at the bottom - but it seems type checking is only possible in 'pure' Javascript/Typescript files.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that in Visual Studio Code, by going to Preferences > Settings and checking Javascript>Implicit Project Config-checkJs.

This should give you some basic intelliSense and mark type errors with familiar red underline.